# How would I use regex to output a specific set of Strings java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a String output of a very long row of movie titles and music album titles.

e.g. 
`[(Pixel Quality) (Year of Release) MovieTitle.ext,...... Albumname-artistname.ext]`

i.e. `[(HD 1080p) (2015) Batman vs Superman.mov,........tearsinheavan-ericclapton.mp3,.......]`

I am trying to identify the movies and music apart using regex expressions. A movie has pixel quality, a release date, a movetitle and an extension like (.mov,.flv...etc) while music has an album name followed by a `-` and the artist name with an extension like (.mp3,.aax.....).

The expected output would be `(Pixel Quality) (Year of Release) MovieTitle.ext` for a movie, and `Albumname-artistname.ext` for music.

I am not too familiar with regex I only know how to match single characters, or a specific word. However I can't seem to output the whole pixel quality,year of release and movietitle.ext. Only the specific words I've matched or the single characters.

Method I used to try and find the "categories".

```
public void FindPatterns () {

        String patternFilms = ("REGEX PATTERN?");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternFilms);

        for (String name : names) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);

            while(matcher.find()){

                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }
        }

    }
```

UPDATE:

I've attempted to fiddle around with the regex patterns in my code, and I get nothing but syntax errors being flagged asking me to delete the tokens, I can't find a clear enough example for what I am trying to achieve.

Just incase I've been putting the pattern in the wrong place this whole time, I've been putting the regex pattern in `String pattern` and `"REGEX PATTERN?` is just a placeholder where I am asking if that is the correct place to put the pattern.

Comment: Why can't you split the string by comma (",")?

Comment: @mks it's a java programming exercise for school. A restriction we have is to not use any methods from the String class. I haven't been able to find any good examples that could help me so I tried asking here... it's still not quite helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the java side of things, your code needs to extract each individual group as a named or indexed group. That's (relatively) the easy part though. Before you get to that point, it sounds like you need help with your pattern, so lets look at that first.

Build up your regex piece by piece. A tool that allows you to quickly iterate your regex is useful. I like https://regex101.com/.

What you need to do is select "matching groups" out of the input String. So you want to match everything that you can throw away (things like commas and parentheses), as well as the data you want to extract. For the data you want to extract, surround the regex for each of those pieces of data in parentheses to denote the group.

Your input strings have lots of characters that have special meaning inside a regex, like `[` and `(`. So if you want to match them explicitly, they need to be "escaped". Also keep in mind that when you translate your regex to Java, the `\` character is itself an escape for a Java String, so it needs to be escaped too with another `\`. So, for example, a regex to match a `[` character would be defined like `\\[`.

So, start by matching the entire input:

```
^.*$
```

The `^` character are "anchors" that mean "beginning of the input" and the "end of the input" respectively. The `.` just matches any character, and the `*` matches the previous token (any character) 0, 1, or more times (so everything).

In regex 101, this will highlight the entire input.

The entire string is surrounded with square brackets, so lets match those, and remember they need to be escaped:

```
^\[.*\]$
```

Now lets start breaking up the individual components. The first two are delimited by parentheses, and remember we need to escape parentheses, so lets match `(something) (something) something`:

```
^\[\(.*\) \(.*\) .*\]$
```

Now again the whole input should be highlighted again. Lets pull out the two pieces of data we just identified by surrounding them in parentheses:

```
^\[\((.*)\) \((.*)\) .*\]$
```

Now you should see the matches highlighted and shown over on the right side. Now continue to build up the regex, replacing that last `.*` with more specific matches.

Comment on this answer if you run into any particular issue!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's parenthesized and then comma separated, so something along the lines of ^[((.*))((.*?)),(.*),(.*)]$

^ matches the start of the line, and $ matches the start of the line
\ escapes characters that have special regex meaning, like [. You need [ and ( to match literal brackets and parentheses. 
(...) marks a group, so that you can extract it when you get a match.
.* is just zero or more repetitions of any character. Use .+ to get one or more repetitions.
Also, add " *" where needed to match spaces.

An example in Perl:

```
echo "(hd)(2015) Avatar.ext, Douchebagson.ext" | perl -pe "s/^\((.*)\) *\((.*)\) *(.*) *, *(.*)$/\1,\2,\3,\4/g"
hd,2015,Avatar.ext,Douchebagson.ext
```

What's happening is a substitution. We're substituting the input string with <1st part>,<2nd part>,.... The result is a csv-format that can be interpreted by your language of choice, Excel or what ever.

`\((.*)\)` matches everything within parentheses. The parentheses are not part of the capturing group, since the literal parentheses /( and /) are outside the capturing clause (.*).
^ and $ are not necessary here, but can be used to find matches only near the end or near the beginning.

Comment: For $ do you mean it matches the end of the line? Also, how would I do it in my context? Because the symbols alone confuse me somehow.

Comment: An example in Perl:
echo "(hd)(2015) Avatar.ext, Douchebagson.ext" | perl -pe "s/^\((.*)\) *\((.*)\) *(.*) *, *(.*)$/\1,\2,\3,\4/g"
hd,2015,Avatar.ext,Douchebagson.ext
^ and $ are not necessary here, but can be used to  \( : 
(.*)\) *\((.*)\) *(.*) *, *(.*)$

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I am not getting it. I've been fiddling around a bit to try to get it to work. But I get syntax error flags asking me to delete the tokens, or I get no output at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Since it's a school assignment, I'm not going to explain what's happening so leaving to your imagination. You should be able to explain it to your teacher.

Try following code:

```
String data = "(HD 1080p) (2015) Batman vs Superman.mov," +
        "tearsinheavan-ericclapton.mp3," +
        "(HD 1080p) (2015) Batman vs Superman.mov," +
        "tearsinheavan-ericclapton.mp3,(HD 1080p) (2015) Batman vs Superman.mov," +
        "tearsinheavan-ericclapton.mp3,";

String rxString = "(?ism)(?<movie>\\(.*?\\) \\(\\d{4}\\).*?\\." +
        "\\w+(?=[,\n]))|(?<music>[^(,\n]*?\\-[^,]+)";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(rxString);

Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(data);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    String movie = regexMatcher.group("movie");
    String music = regexMatcher.group("music");

    if(movie!=null) {
        System.out.printf("Movie:\t%s\n", movie);
    }

    if(music!=null) {
        System.out.printf("Music:\t%s\n", music);
    }
}
```

It will printout:

```
Movie:  (HD 1080p) (2015) Batman vs Superman.mov
Music:  tearsinheavan-ericclapton.mp3
Movie:  (HD 1080p) (2015) Batman vs Superman.mov
Music:  tearsinheavan-ericclapton.mp3
Movie:  (HD 1080p) (2015) Batman vs Superman.mov
Music:  tearsinheavan-ericclapton.mp3
```

Comment: I am getting an error at `.matcher` because my `data` is from an ArrayList<String> which was converted from an ArrayList<Media>. The Media object consists of a String and Image (JLabel and ImageIcon). I will try turning the ArrayList into a String and see if this fixes it..

Comment: Well, this is a separate problem. You can merge ArrayList<String> to string.

Comment: Or repeat above snippet for each element of ArrayList. There are pros and cons but as student you should evaluate your options.

Comment: Your note is amusing. I took the opposite approach: since it's a school assignment, I wouldn't just provide the solution, but rather try and explain how he needs to approach the problem.

Comment: Well, we both provided half baked solution so either way is correct.